# Getting error when creating a multi step test in azure Application insights Multi step test

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, web-performance

I opened visual studio 2015 and created a web performance and load test project. I started the recording and pasted the link of my website and clicked a button. I stopped the recording. I saved the file and did a run test. The webpage did not open up, but I got a green tick saying Passed. I uploaded the .webtest file, but get the following error.

```
Creating web test "t1" failed with error:"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Visual Studio Web Test (Id = 'application_t1-applicationinsightstest_us-il-ch1-azr') has no items.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable the Add on in the browser Microsoft Webtest Recorder